# adding Event Listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i am facing a problem with event add event listener function it don't give an error it is just not working i even listened to videos copied and pasted other codes to work and modify my html to work with but it add event listener doesn't work here is my code bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Main page of a simple website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mstn.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_parent">click here to go to google</a>
            <a href="victimclient.rar" download="victimclient.rar">here</a>

        <p id="demo">testing testing testing </p>
        <p>testing testing testing</p>
        <h1>whats little g</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="checkthisout.js">
            y = document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
        if(y){
            function myFunction() { 
                alert("hello world")
            }
        }

        </script>
        <input holder="password" value="replace here" id="input"/>



    </body>
```

Comment: Why put the function definition inside an if condition? It's not needed. The function **needs to be defined** when you add the event listener, otherwise nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Main page of a simple website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mstn.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <header>
            <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_parent">click here to go to google</a>
            <a href="victimclient.rar" download="victimclient.rar">here</a>

        <p id="demo">testing testing testing </p>
        <p>testing testing testing</p>
        <h1>whats little g</h1>
        
        <input holder="password" value="replace here" id="input"/>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() {
                 document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
            }
          
            function myFunction() { 
                alert("hello world")
            }

        </script>
    </body>
```

Here is the solution.
You have to wait that the DOM has been loaded before manipulate it.
Moreover you can't have `src` attribute in this `script` tag.

Comment: Why is this the solution? Please expand your answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running before the input is generated so it's probably not finding it. Try putting the script at the end or use Jquery's document.ready function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Main page of a simple website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mstn.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_parent">click here to go to google</a>
            <a href="victimclient.rar" download="victimclient.rar">here</a>

        <p id="demo">testing testing testing </p>
        <p>testing testing testing</p>
        <h1>whats little g</h1>

        <input holder="password" value="replace here" id="input"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="checkthisout.js">

            function myFunction() { 
                alert("hello world")
            }

            document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("click", myFunction);




        </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Why assume jQuery? There's no jQuery in the question.

Comment: It's just another possibility. I answered the question and then provided another way to do it.

Comment: I understand, but the OP hasn't put jquery as a tag, and the question never asks for it.

Comment: I understand that as well, but maybe he doesn't know about jquery and it would be useful for him to know.

Comment: I agree, but it's still not wise to answer a plain js question with a library specific answer.

Comment: Which is why I answered it without the library specific answer at first. I'm happy to edit it out of my answer, but I don't see how it's hurting.

Comment: No hurt. I saw your answer without the code, and jumped on you without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Your order of html and scripts matters and also you cant have function defined inside if(y){}, because that function defination scope is under 'if' which is not available to addEventListner level. Try this:

```
 <input holder="password" value="replace here" id="input1"/>

        <script>

         y =  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);

   function myFunction() { 
                alert("hello world")
            }

        </script>
```